# How to update user profile information dynamically using facebook Api?

Tags: facebook

I want to update the user information for my profile dynamically.Is it possible to update user information in my profile using facebook api.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to edit a user's information using the Graph API.  This relies on Facebook's own interfaces.

This is understandable from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Not all of the user information can be edited by graph-api. Specially, Facebook profile, it cannot be edited by graph-api.