# Can we change the cover image of a Facebook account from my application using iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to change the image of my cover in the `Facebook Timeline` from an `iPhone` application programmatically?

Comment: I don't think you can : here is a [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872647/how-to-update-user-profile-information-dynamically-using-facebook-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the cover photo of your profile?

If so, then no - it's not possible to change the cover picture from any iOS application currently.